# Fish shell reports "math: Error: Missing operator" on tab completion

Tags: shell, command-line, configuration, autocomplete, fish

I noticed the error this morning, but I don't think I have changed anything last night, so I am very confused right now. Perhaps I updated some utilities on my system and it somehow broke the back compatibility. Basically I got a `math: Error: Missing operator` error when using tab completion.

Say I type `fish`, and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get the suggestions like `fish_config` and `fish_add_path` (here is an asciinema screencast in case you want to see it in action: https://asciinema.org/a/L3xr32eVMGHuCY0Gjr19gFzCu)

```
[I] ~ $ fishmath: Error: Missing operator
'Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969 - 1655913830'
 ^
[I] ~ $ fish_config
fish                                                                               (command)
fish_add_path
fish_breakpoint_prompt
fish_clipboard_copy
…and 29 more rows
```

The tab completion does work, but the error looks very annoying. Looks like I am trying to evaluate a data string or something. How do I diagnose the bug?

---

I am on macOS Monterey. Here is my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

```
set -px PATH /opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin
set -px PATH $HOME/.local/bin
set -px PATH $HOME/bin
set -px PATH /Applications/MacPorts/Alacritty.app/Contents/MacOS
set -px PATH $HOME/Foreign/drawterm
set -px PATH $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin

set -x XDG_CONFIG_HOME $HOME/.config
set -x PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT 1
set -x PLAN9 /usr/local/plan9

set -px PATH $PLAN9/bin

if test -e $HOME/.config/fish/sensitive.fish
    source $HOME/.config/fish/sensitive.fish
end

if status is-interactive
    # Commands to run in interactive sessions can go here
    alias vi='/opt/local/bin/nvim'
    set -gx EDITOR /opt/local/bin/nvim
    source /opt/local/share/fzf/shell/key-bindings.fish
end

set -g fish_key_bindings fish_hybrid_key_bindings

alias matlab='/Applications/MATLAB_R2021b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay'

zoxide init fish | source

direnv hook fish | source

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/qys/google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc' ]; . '/Users/qys/google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc'; end
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. If possible, also try logging in as a different user and checking if the error appears there too, otherwise we can know it is a problem specific to your normal user.

Comment: @terdon I have edited the question. I am on macOS, and I am effectively the only user on the system.

Comment: Thanks, and double thanks for taking the time to post your solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error goes away after I remove the line `set -px PATH $PLAN9/bin`. I guess it was because I accidentally shadowed some system utilities with its counterpart in [Plan 9 from User Space](https://9fans.github.io/plan9port/).

Another workaround is to use `set -ax PATH $PLAN9/bin` instead. By using `-a`, the directory `$PLAN9/bin` is appended to `$PATH` (as opposed to prepended when using `-p`), so that the commands already present in `$PATH` takes precedence over the Plan 9 ones.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that fish tries to complete commands, and it tries to add descriptions to them by calling `apropos`.

On macOS, this is super slow because Apple's sandboxing breaks the whatis database.

So, fish adds its own caching instead, and this cache is updated once a week.

Only to check that date, [it runs](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/61b09ff4a793397f2f3766b8f1802da469a68792/share/functions/__fish_apropos.fish#L39):

```
set age (math (date +%s) - (/usr/bin/stat -f %m $whatis))
```

Giving `date` the `+%s` format specifier to get just the unix epoch.

You had overridden `date` with the (as is typical) ultra-minimalist [Plan 9 version](https://9fans.github.io/plan9port/man/man1/date.html), which doesn't take a format argument, so it ends up printing a full date, which makes the math expression malformed.

In general, fish assumes a reasonably standard unix userspace, and so prepending Plan 9 tools (which aren't) is a bad idea.